# taking big integer input all at a time in C++

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

i want to take a 1000 digit integer input all at a time,& want to add the digits separately.is there any input method to take such a large input?

Comment: If you are using a string you can use a for-loop

Answer (score 4):

You need to input that as a string. Split them, and convert each character to an integer. Add them up, and you're done.

Example, this number here (randomly generated):

```
9624526619162264306083309360203157186784123851390498919674886891002552146753945797326679482200717699585297042606470048297021049209667042255911984240697992738371633115195140494325737382583412562136836759072897211537655046343769659111215754043609344618490646811291135643554115350431099553593485744944746093896695837300975718819726339233383800764568364950577294931831936979504756278187812548901366714205562309364234394802723329400976924082450161974562063268243689930750925213262044910428021004262080895556879515597779404780565380480750286553508081070834339176079062215815331059349488936312244526697733596052063044560959189161656978673936732284706841120711543620038686227462170335634371808995466024671420024705248851244350701111587608201303840696489479021196275228499780922745352396928865910631672384263395712487735712098161853665189905194589355110620257494673972892816413534347360049692019184831019218764766067298983043791063184786671132332077197148683743991683245617836086353821268720434176862469084808
```

And here's the C++ program:

```
int strint(std::string &str) {
    int i;
    std::stringstream intstr(str);
    intstr >> i;
    return i;
}

int main () {
    std::string strdigit, schar;
    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter Digits: ";
    std::cin >> strdigit;
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < strdigit.length(); i++) {
        ss.clear();
        ss << strdigit[i];
        ss >> schar;
        sum += strint(schar);
    }
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

The sum is: `4479`

Answer (score 2):

Simply read the digits into a string and use std::accumulate. For example:

```
std::string str("1234567890"); // your number here

int result = std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), 0, [](int val, char ch)
{
    return val + (ch - '0');
});

std::cout << result << '\n'; // display the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a library to provide support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read the digits into a string and use a multiprecision math library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) to do the addition.  The library should have functions for converting between digit strings and the library's internal representation for numbers.

(Actually, it looks like GMP can read digits directly from an `istream`, so you may not even need a string.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the question. If you are adding the digits separately, then I would have thought you were treating it more as a string than an integer (at least, until you start adding up the digits).

Can you clarify how the 1,000-digit integer needs to be stored in memory?

Comment: I'm not very much sure about whether i should take input as a string or an integer.if i take it as a string,then how can i convert each digit into a integer?

Comment: @nafiz amin: The simplest way to convert a character digit to an integer is to subtract the character constant '0' from your character. For example: if your character is '1' (ASCII 49) and you subtract '0' (ASCII 48) the result is the integer 1. See my and andreas' answers.

Answer (score 0):

As marlon suggested, why not simply use good 'ol for loop and string?

```
int main() {
        string str = "3985792792679283635";
        int len = str.length();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sum += str[i] - '0';
        }
        cout << sum << endl;

}
```